# How can we change the height and width of the close button in react-bootstrap?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

```
<CloseButton className="crossBtn"/>
.crossBtn{
    height:37px;
    width:32px;
}
```

How can I change the width and height of the close button ? If I write like this it is not changing.

Comment: Please include more of the file for context. Are you writing that css right under the JSX? Because the css should be in a separate file that you import.

Comment: No,css is in the seperate file only .

Comment: consider applying the styles directly as inline styles in your React component and marked as !important. This can sometimes help to override external styles.

Answer (score 1):

CloseButton Component internally uses background images.
so solution is :

```
<CloseButton className="crossBtn"/>
.crossBtn{
    width: 32px;
    height: 37px;
    background-size: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you use external css file ? If so, your external is probably called before bootstrap style so its overwriten.

You can try this :

```
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';

function VariantsExample() {
  return (
    <>
      <style type="text/css">
        {`
    .btn-close {
      width: 2em;
      height: 2em;
      border: 1px solid red;
    }
    `}
      </style>

      <CloseButton />
    </>
  );
}

export default VariantsExample;
```

Then import your custom button instead of Bootstrap one.